# Take the contents from textbox in first div and then display it in Second div in label format?

Tags: javascript

I have to take the contents from textbox in first div and then display it in Second div in label format, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<div id="myText">myText</div>
<div id="myLable"></div>
```

js

```
var textField = document.getElementById('myText');
var lableField = document.getElementById('myLable');
lableField.innerText = textField.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
javasctipt:

function copyDiv() {
    var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv1');
    var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv2');
    secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;
}

//Call copyDiv on body="onload"
copyDiv();
```

html :

```
<div id="mydiv1">
    1
    2
</div>
<div id="mydiv2"></div>
```

innerHTML should work for you and sorry for the late reply i was typing this from memory and had to test